# Check if NSString contains alphanumeric + underscore characters only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a string that needs to be only a-z, 0-9 and _

How do I check if the input is valid? I've tried this but it accepts letter like å,ä,ö,ø etc.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:nameField.text];
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet];
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];
BOOL valid = [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can create your own character set:

```
NSCharacterSet *s = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_"];
```

Once you have that, you invert it to everything that's not in your original string:

```
s = [s invertedSet];
```

And you can then use a string method to find if your string contains anything in the inverted set:

```
NSRange r = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:s];
if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"the string contains illegal characters");
}
```

Comment: But what if the user wants to add in the equivalent of A to Z in another language like Chinese?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff there is no alphabet in Chinese. Maybe you are confusing with Japanese's Hiragana and Katakana. Or you mean the whole CJK Unified Ideographs, and that's 80,388 of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs

Comment: @Cœur my point was, how can you ensure that this checks the user has entered numbers only in ANY language. This just checks it in English.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Well, we are off subject, as it's not specific to this answer, so I'll not add more comments here. But underscore character is not part of English alphabet anyway ^_^.

Comment: @Dave DeLong : How can we specify whiteSpace also in :  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_"];

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal make that an `NSMutableCharacterSet` and `formUnion` with that set and the whitespace character set.

Answer (score 38):

You can use a predicate:

```
NSString *myRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z_]*"; 
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myRegex]; 
NSString *string = nameField.text;
BOOL valid = [myTest evaluateWithObject:string];
```

**Edit:**
I don't noticed that you are using `[NSString stringWithString:nameField.text]`.

Use `nameField.text` instead.

Comment: @Sinetris What does the * at the end of myRegex do?  This works like a champ!  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Some more easy way,

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_"];
[allowedSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
NSCharacterSet *forbiddenSet = [allowedSet invertedSet];
```

It'll combine alphanumeric along with _underscore.

you can use it like,

```
NSRange r = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:forbiddenSet];
if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"the string contains illegal characters");
}
```

PS. example copied from @DaveDeLong example :)

Comment: The question specifically gives the example of `alphanumericCharacterSet` not being the desired solution as it accepts å,ä,ö,ø, etc.

Comment: This answer is so sweet now I have diabetes.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own character set using `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:]`, then trim as you were doing to see if the returned string has a length value.

Or you could use `invertedSet` to remove all non-set characters, if that would help to produce a cleaned string.

Answer (score 3):

You could loop through the every character in the string and check that it's alphanumeric:

```
BOOL isMatch = YES;
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    if (!isalnum(c) && c != '_') {
        isMatch = NO;
        break;
    }
}
if (isMatch) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it in Swift (as an extension of the String class):

```
extension String {

     func containsValidCharacters() -> Bool {

        var charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")
        charSet = charSet.invertedSet

        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charSet)

        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @vikzilla answer for **Swift 5**:

```
extension String {

    func containsValidCharacters() -> Bool {

        var charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")
        charSet = charSet.inverted as NSCharacterSet

        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet as CharacterSet as CharacterSet)

        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this is a quick helper if it helps

```
-(BOOL)isString:(NSString *)s{
    char letter = 'A';
    //BOOL isLetter=NO;
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",letter+i];
        if ([s isEqualToString:temp]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This algorithm only works for strings containing a single uppercase character.