# Check : Whether my string contain any character except specified characters (M,d,y,-,/,:,h,D,Y,m,S,s,\,_)

Tags: objective-c, regex, ios7, nsregularexpression

I am trying implement filter/expression to check my string not contain any character except these `(M,d,y,-,/,:,h,D,Y,m,S,s,\,_).`

Please help to write regular expression to verify that string should not contain any character except specified `character set (M,d,y,-,/,:,h,D,Y,m,S,s,\,_)`

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546235/check-if-nsstring-contains-alphanumeric-underscore-characters-only

Comment: Regular expression is overkill for this.

Comment: If your using textField or textView then you could utilise shouldChangeCharactersInRange method or put condition in text begin to check for specified character.

Comment: Its not duplicate because i have tried with all possibilities and it was not working properly. What i needed is specific character set and thanks to Barmar for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
[^(Mdy\-/:hDYmSs\\_)]
```

will match any character outside that set.

Comment: Do you need to escape that `-` character within the `[]` group?

Comment: Yeah, thanks -- I thought I was watching for that character, but still missed it.

Answer (score 1):

If your string can **only** contain these characters, you can validate it with this regex:

```
^[-/:MmDdYyhSs,_\\]+$
```

- Match => it's a good string
- No match => it contains other characters